# Split a string into unicode words? (particularly Vietnamese)

Tags: java, string, split

I have been trying to split a string that contains text in Vietnamese into individual words. For example:

> s = "Chào bạn, mình tên Đạt."

Will be splitted into an array:

> arr = {"Chào", "bạn", "mình", "tên", "Đạt"}

Normally in English, this would be easily solve by 1 line only:

```
arr = s.split("\\W+");
```

but since there are many non-alphabetic letters in Vietnamese, it can't be solve by just one line. So the question is: Is there any regular expressions that can replace this "\W+" (I'm not very good with regular expressions)? If not, is there any other ways around it?

Comment: How about using `"\\s"` to split on [whitespaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef)? Plus maybe punctuation characters as needed.

Comment: That would result in {"Chào", "bạn,", "mình", "tên", "Đạt."} which contains punctuation marks

Answer (score 2):

Split a String by space and punctuation. You can add your punctuation. As some of the characters in regex are reserved, I prefer to use them a in a character class `[]`.

```
arr = s.split("([ ]|[.]|[,]|[:]|[?])+"); //You can customize punctuation.
```

This is a working example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String  inputStr = "Chào bạn, mình tên Đạt.";
   String [] splitArray = inputStr.split("([ ]|[.]|[,]|[:]|[?])+");
   for (String s : splitArray) {
       System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

Prints:

```
Chào
bạn
mình
tên
Đạt
```

### Update

In case of simple space character `[ ]`, it works well. However, for this String.

```
 String  inputStr = "Chào  bạn,\n mình tên\t Đạt.";
```

Result

```
Chào
bạn


mình
tên 
Đạt
```

To fix it, use space character class - `\s`.

```
  String [] splitArray = inputStr.split("(\\s|[.]|[,]|[:]|[?])+");
```

Or loop through the array of Strings, and trim them.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and have thought of it before. But my strings don't contains only `. , : ?` as punctuation marks. But if I can't find any other ways, I will definitely use this solution.

Comment: Then update the regex. Find out which punctuation characters you need, and just add them into the regex.